# NSWindow and text smoothing in NSTableView cell view

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nswindow, nstableviewcell

I'm writing an OS X app and have a problem with font smoothing in separate window.

I have a text field where you put text and suggestion window which pops up with a list of suggestions according to what you wrote. I'm using View-cell based `NSTableView` to display those suggestions and `SFBPopoverWindowController`  to display it as a "popup" window (tried other classes with the same effect). When rows are first drawn they look fine but after I select them (keyboard or mouse) the font changes it's weight. It's only visual - like you would change smoothing method on the font, not it's bold setting.

[image: Font smoothing problem within cell]

*"Music note" is the selected cell here*

What's even more strange is that after I hide and show the window 3 times everything works fine from that point on.

[image: Font smoothing problem after showing the window 3 times]

*Again - "Music note" is the selected cell.*

The selection is done by overwriting `NSTableRowView` class and its `drawSelectionInRect:` method but I tried with drawing everything inside custom `NSTableCellView` class and it didn't help. The text is standard `NSTextField` - nothing's changed there.

The SFBPopoverWindow (and it's controller) are created once and reused with styleMask `NSBorderlessWindowMask`, backing `NSBackingStoreBuffered`, defer set to `YES`. The only change in `SFBPopoverWindowController` I made was to turn off window becoming key window but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I have seen this problem myself with a custom view that lays out a lot of text.  After redrawing some parts of the text with highlight (different background colour) the text would appear "jaggy".  I didn't find an answer but it went away after I converted to using CALayers.  I know this doesn't help, but I feel it's a bug in both 10.7 and 10.8.

Answer (score 3):

It might be related to the way a table view draws it's selected cells (`setSelectionHightLightStyle:`). Try to set the style to None/ `NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleNone` in your code or IB / Storyboard-file and draw the selection yourself (in a `NSTableRowView` subclass).

Background: When you use `NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleRegular` or `NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList` the table view assumes that you use the standard selection behaviour and appearance and does some magic to support that.

==========

**UPDATE**

==========

My previous answer is still valid but since it only describes the problem and hints at a workaround, I wanted to add a real solution. If you want to use `NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleRegular` for your table view (with custom font and colors), you need a way to 'disable' the system magic that comes into place once your row is highlighted. One proposed solution is to  [decline the first responder status](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26990727/3184888). It has a lot of drawbacks and isn't a good solution at all.

So, let's have a closer look at the system 'magic' that kicks in as soon as the row will be highlighted: `NSTableRowView` has a property interiorBackgroundStyle that is – according to the documentation – '*an indication of how the subviews should draw*'. Furthermore '*This value is dynamically computed based on the set of properties set for the NSTableRowView. Subclassers can override this value when they draw differently based on the currently displayed properties. This method can also be called to determine what color a subview should use, or alternatively, NSControls can have the -backgroundStyle set on their cell to this value.*'

I assume that this style will be handed down the subview hierarchy and causes your text fields to look odd. The system assumes that a highlighted cell has a dark background and changes the `interiorBackgroundStyle` to dark. Other controls try to adapt accordingly.

I think there are two solutions to this problem:

1) Override `interiorBackgroundStyle` in your `NSTableRowView` subclass and return the style that fits your interface (in my case it's `.light` because my highlight color is a very bright blue). This worked for me.

2) If changing the whole style is a bit too much because you only want certain elements to not change their style, you may only need to adjust these subclasses. I haven't tried this yet.

Comment: Jan, you just saved my sanity. I didn't think the AppKit engineers were doing magical drawing stuff when "Regular" was selected. I assumed any "special" stuff was limited to the "Source List" style. Holy cow. Thank you. My table looks so sexy now. Future Googlers, read this answer. It just saved a man's life.

Comment: Overriding interiorBackgroundStyle worked like a charm for me. Strangely, in my app the problem only manifested itself on non-Retina displays. Text in my NSTableView on Retina displays looked fine. Irregardless, this fix worked. Thanks!