# Custom selection style for view based "Source List" NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview, appkit

I'm using a view based `NSOutlineView` that has it's `selectionHighlightStyle` set to `NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList`.

I want to overwrite the selection style (background) for certain rows and draw a different color/gradient.

What I tried so far is creating a custom `NSTableRowView` and returning it via `outlineView:rowViewForItem:`.
I verified that my custom row views are created and returned by the outline view delegate.
However, none of the methods I'm overwriting in the custom row view are being called.

I tried to overwrite `drawBackgroundInRect:`, `drawSelectionInRect:`, `drawSeparatorInRect:` and even `drawRect:`. None of those are called, ever.

I'm suspecting the outline view to be doing some custom "magic" when it's set to the source list style, but I've not found anything in the documentation that indicates that a custom `NSTableRowView` wouldn't be honored at all in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Yosemite?
From Apple's document [Adopting Advanced Features of the new UI in Yosemite](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/220xx01yweszmjv/220/220_adopting_advanced_features_of_the_new_ui_of_os_x_yosemite.pdf?dl=1)

> When selectionHighlightStyle ==
>   NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList • Selection is now a
>   special blue material that does behind window blending 
>   - The material size and drawing can not be customized

If you set it to NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleRegular and override the drawRect, it should work.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Yosemite and although I have watched the WWDC session you're referencing, I seem to have missed "The material size and drawing can not be customized". Looks I'm out of luck if I want both, use the Source List style and customize selection drawing for several rows.

Comment: Are you trying to remove the blue highlight? If so, you might be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26596621/how-to-get-the-source-lists-selection-highlight-to-use-the-dark-vibrancy-appeara/26990727#26990727

Comment: That's definitely useful and I have just implemented this in another part of my app. Awesome finding! However, in this particular case, I'd like to overwrite the default blue highlight to be a completely different color/gradient.

Comment: `drawSelectionInRect:` is called again in El Capitan.

Comment: @ylian how do you make `drawSelectionInRect:` it called in El Capitan?

Comment: For me drawSelectionInRect is not called in El Captain

Answer (score 4):

AppKit adds separate `NSVisualEffectView` with custom material to row view for drawing background when using `NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleSourceList`. I've come up with the following workaround which uses zero private APIs, but can break later if Apple implements some other way of highlighting rows.

```
@class CustomHighlightRowSelectionView;
@interface CustomHighlightRowView : NSTableRowView

@property (nonatomic, strong) CustomHighlightRowSelectionView *selectionView;

@end

@interface CustomHighlightRowSelectionView : NSView

@property (nonatomic, getter=isEmphasized) BOOL emphasized;
@property (nonatomic, getter=isSelected) BOOL selected;

@end


@implementation CustomHighlightRowView

- (CustomHighlightRowSelectionView *)selectionView
{
    if (!_selectionView)
    {
        _selectionView = [[CustomHighlightRowSelectionView alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    }

    return _selectionView;
}

- (void)setEmphasized:(BOOL)emphasized
{
    [super setEmphasized:emphasized];
    self.selectionView.emphasized = emphasized;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
    [super setSelected:selected];
    self.selectionView.selected = selected;
}

- (void)addSubview:(NSView *)aView positioned:(NSWindowOrderingMode)place relativeTo:(NSView *)otherView
{
    if (![aView isKindOfClass:[NSVisualEffectView class]])
    {
        [super addSubview:aView positioned:place relativeTo:otherView];
    }
    else
    {
        if (!self.selectionView.superview)
        {
            [super addSubview:self.selectionView positioned:place relativeTo:otherView];
            self.selectionView.frame = self.bounds;
        }
    }
}

- (void)setFrame:(NSRect)frame
{
    [super setFrame:frame];

    self.selectionView.frame = self.bounds;
}

- (void)setBounds:(NSRect)bounds
{
    [super setBounds:bounds];

    self.selectionView.frame = self.bounds;
}

@end

@implementation CustomHighlightRowSelectionView

- (void)setEmphasized:(BOOL)emphasized
{
    _emphasized = emphasized;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected
{
    _selected = selected;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    if (!self.selected)
    {
        return;
    }

    NSColor *fillColor = self.emphasized ? [NSColor alternateSelectedControlColor] : [NSColor secondarySelectedControlColor];
    [fillColor setFill];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
}

@end
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it is working perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to overwrite -selectionHighlightStyle in your NSTableRowView subclass:

```
- (NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyle)selectionHighlightStyle
{
    return NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleRegular;
}
```

That way, the table view can be used in source list style but with a customized row selection. I wanted to have the source list under Yosemite in my project but with the user-selected color from the System Preferences.

**Edit: I just noticed doing it this way causes text fields and image views inside the cell view to have an artifact like border looking very odd and ugly.**

Comment: I just noticed doing it this way causes text fields and image views inside the cell view to have an artifact like border looking very odd and ugly. Bottom line - the source list style's selection color cannot be adjusted. Instead, I've used the regular style and manually designed the outline view to look like a source list one. Note: If you're targeting Yosemite and you want the translucent background look that is turned on by default when using the source list, you'll need to embed the outline view in an NSVisualEffectView.

Comment: I'm aware of the possibility of using NSTableViewSelectionHighlightStyleRegular and "faking" the source list appearance but I'd rather have non-custom selection styles instead of implementing all the source list styling myself...

Comment: I agree, native is mostly better and more elegant but in this case you might be out of luck, I'm afraid. Finding a way to modify / hack the outline view to have customized selection rows in source list mode will take considerably longer than modifying the view manually.